# Can someone help me remove/fix ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm very new to ubuntu for starters. Whenever I turn my computer on, it opens to the GNU Grub terminal. It says it supports minimal Bash-Like line editing (I have no idea what this means). To work-around this, I used "exit -ubuntu", this then takes me to a separate page which I selected the Windows Boot Manager and click on the Windows 8.1 icon which makes my Windows 8 load normally.

If I click on the other icon, being the ubuntu one, I get put back at the GNU Grub terminal and thats it. If someone could help me either remove ubuntu or repair it so that I can load it again, I would appreciate it. I had installed the most recent ubuntu version.

Comment: It greatly depends how you installed Ubuntu. Did you used wubi?

Comment: I used a flash drive with UUI. Is that what you're asking or did I say something completely unrelated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [instructions from here](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596) to install Ubuntu. Windows 8 secure boot is likely preventing you from booting Ubuntu.

To remove Ubuntu, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).